# Composing objects with > 1024 parts without download/upload

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to either clear the compose count or copy an object inside cloud storage so as to remove the compose count without downloading and uploading again?

With a 5TB object size limit, I'd need 5GB pieces composed together with a 1024 compose limit -- are 5GB uploads even possible?  They are certainly not easy to work with.

The compose count should be higher (1MM) or I should be able to copy an object within cloud storage to get rid of the existing compose count.

Comment: Outside of the answer I posted below, what is the scenario you're envisioning where you need this many components?

Comment: This is all mainly for parallel uploads, so I'm trying to build something that doesn't require a bunch of hacks to upload varying file sizes with a configurable chunk size.

I don't plan on creating a 1TB file, but if I want even a 10GB file, it would seem reasonable to upload it in 100MB chunks with perhaps 8 or 16 parallel uploads at a time...

Comment: gsutil does exactly this with parallel composite uploads: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#parallel-composite-uploads. If you are using a single machine, opening 1024 network connections simultaneously is unlikely to give you optimal performance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no longer a restriction on the component count. Composing > 1024 parts is allowed.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects

Answer (score 1):

5G uploads are definitely possible.  You can use a tool such as [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install?hl=en) to perform them easily.

There's not an easy way to reduce the existing component count, but it is possible using the [Rewrite API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite?hl=en).  Per the documentation: "When you rewrite a composite object where the source and destination are different locations and/or storage classes, the result will be a composite object containing a single component."

So you can create a bucket of a different storage class, rewrite it, then rewrite it back to your original bucket and delete the copy.  gsutil uses the rewrite API under the hood, so you could do all of this with `gsutil cp`:

```
$ gsutil mb -c DRA gs://dra-bucket
$ gsutil cp gs://original-bucket/composite-obj gs://dra-bucket/composite-obj
$ gsutil cp gs://your-dra-bucket/composite-obj gs://original-bucket/composite-obj
$ gsutil rm gs://dra-bucket/composite-obj
```

Comment: This is really really hacky -- and I was talking about 5TB -- does Google have any plans to fix this?

Comment: I agree that it's not ideal, but this is a documented limitation of composite objects.  You can upload 5TB successfully using the resumable upload protocol.